# Inner Class with parameter of Outer Class Type

Tags: java, generics, nested-class

I would like to create an inner class parametrized on the type of the outer class.

I should say first that I realize there may be a better way to achieve something like my desired result, and I am open to suggestions there, but I'll describe the situation as it stands:

I have a class `Node<T>` and an attempt at an inner class declaration as below:

```
public class Node<T> {
    ...

    class NodeIterator<Node<T>> implements Iterator {
        ...
    }
}
```

This causes a syntax error during compilation, and I infer that this is due to the my use of the outer class, although I do not know this for sure.

Thanks!

Comment: The syntax error is nothing to do with this being an inner class; the problem is the part inside `< >` in your declaration of `NodeIterator`.  Either `NodeIterator` is a generic class, in which case you might declare it as something like `NodeIterator<U>`; or it isn't, in which case you would declare it just as `NodeIterator`.  But declaring it as `NodeIterator<Node<T>>` makes no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do:

```
public class Node<T> {
    ...

    class NodeIterator implements Iterator<Node<T>> {
        ...
    }
}
```

As an inner class, an instance of `NodeIterator` has an implicit reference to an outer `Node` instance. For this reason, the type `T` is still in scope within its body.

Note that an alternative would be to make `NodeIterator` `static`, losing the implicit outer reference:

```
static class NodeIterator<T> implements Iterator<Node<T>> {
    ...
}
```

Here, `T` must be declared anew, and is different from the `T` declared by the outer class.

See the [Java Tutorials article on nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for more info.

Comment: As I posted my comment, you edited your answer - good timing. I'll remove the comment to avoid confusion!

Comment: @Muel Thanks for prodding me about that actually, I realized I should have the correct code out front.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the generic type argument on the `Iterator` interface instead of the inner class.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Node<T> {


    class NodeIterator implements Iterator<Node<T>> {

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Node<T> next() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }    
    }
}
```

I suspect the language does not allow this because nothing would stop you from instantiating a concrete type that does not match the outer classes type such as:

```
//calling code
Node<Integer> node = new Node<Integer>();

//Node.java
public class Node<T>{

    NodeIterator<String> nodeIterator = new NodeIterator<String>();
}
```